# Lorentz tensor - always outer product of two four-vectors?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

A 2nd rank Lorentz tensor is defined as one that transforms as:
$$T'=\Lambda T\Lambda^T$$
It is clear that the quantity:
$$\tilde A \tilde B^T$$
where $\tilde A$ and $\tilde B$ are 4-vectors always transforms in this way and as such is a Lorentz tensor. However is the reverse true i.e. given a 2nd rank Lorentz tensor $T$ can it always be written as the outer product of two 4-vectors and either way can it proved?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

As a counterexample, take the tensor with all components equal to zero except for $T^{12}=-T^{21}=1$ and $T^{ii}=1$. If it was a product $T^{ij}=A^iB^j$ then $A^1B^2=1=A^2B^2$ and $-A^2B^1=1=A^1B^1$. It is clear that $B^1,B^2\neq 0$ so we can obtain $A^1=A^2$ and $A^1=-A^2$, which implies $A^1=0$. This is in contradiction with the statement $A^1\neq 0$ that can be derived from the equation $A^1B^1=1$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that *not* every tensor may be decomposed as the tensor product of "components" (a "simple tensor"). This simply follows from the definition of the tensor product:

Given two vector spaces $V,W$ with bases $\{v_i\}_{i\in I},\{w_j\}_{j\in J}$, the tensor product $V\otimes W$ is the space spanned by all possible combinations $\{v_i\otimes w_j\}_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ of these basis vectors, i.e. a generic element  $T$ of $V\otimes W$ is written
$$ T = \sum_{i,j} T_{ij} (v_i\otimes w_j).$$

The simple tensors, that is, the image of the map $V\times W\to V\otimes W, (a,b)\mapsto a\otimes b$, where we defined
$$ a\otimes b = (\sum_i a_i v_i)\otimes (\sum_j b_j w_j) := \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j (v_i\otimes b_j),$$
is not even a vector subspace of $V\otimes W$. For example, $v_1\otimes w_1$ and $v_2\otimes w_2$ clearly lie in it, but $v_1\otimes w_1 + v_2\otimes w_2$ clearly does not.

These "tensors" are the same tensors you are talking about when we recognize that a "rank-2 tensor" $\Lambda$ is just a linear map $M\to M, x^\mu \mapsto \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$ on Minkowski space $M$ and use that the space of linear maps fulfills $\mathrm{Lin}(V,W) = V\otimes W$ for finite-dimensional spaces, so the space of rank-2 tensors is $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\otimes \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$.